# jquery message windows / dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, messagebox

I have some ajax calls in one of my pages.  On complete I want do display a simple message letting the user know that the operation has been completed. maybe with an ok button that they can click to close the window.  Alert("message") would work if I could remove the title and that scary "!" icon.

Any jquery/javascript sugestions?  -Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the jquery ui Dialog plugin:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You can customize it to suit your needs, and add what ever kind of buttons you want. It's just HTML inside the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a modal dialog.  Check out the modal dialog in jQuery UI  http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Basically when the AJAX request is completed and successful you can open your dialog with an ok button and display whatever title you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I like [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). It also has a confirm style dialog - this looks similar to the default alert/confirm dialogs. You can see a demo [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/).